# Transpose Rows to Column Oracle (APEX)

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a table (Table A) :

[image]

And I would like to show this table in APEX as Editable Interactive Grid so:

[image]

What should I do ? Which SQl Statement gives this result ?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Thank you for edit Barbaros.

Comment: You say you want an **editable** Interactive Grid. That means you don't want just one "statement" that will give you a result to show, you want the Grid to be able to update values. Do you really want the user to be able to change the data in this Grid?

Comment: First of all, thank you for your interest. Yes, the user can/will change the data in this Grid.

Comment: Since you want the user to be able to change the data, there is no one "SQL statement" that will meet your requirement. You could conceivably write a VIEW to produce the format you want, then write an INSTEAD OF trigger on the view to change the base table. Seems yucky to me. By the way, what if there is more than one ID? What if there is more than one year?

Comment: Ok, thank you. I am working on it.

Comment: I have changed my data structure and with Decode I have solved the Problem. Thanks for your Comments.